# Converting structured data to a dataset

Tags: version-10, dataset

A Dataset seems perfect to represent structured data.

Has anyone already thought about how to convert as efficiently/elegantly as possible an XML or JSON file to a Dataset in Mathematica 10 ?

Comment: An example of converting XML to a dataset can be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58527/142).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To convert JSON to `Dataset` we can use `` GeneralUtilities`ToAsssociations `` as was first mentioned by [rm-rf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/rm-rf) [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16590486#16590486).

Example using the Stackexchange API (the ten most up voted posts, questions and answers, on this site):

```
json = Import["http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts?pagesize=10&order=desc&sort=votes&site=mathematica&filter=!LH22RQM95veNmsOfuhD0xa", "JSON"]
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
dataset = Dataset[ToAssociations@json]["items"]
```

[image]

For the record, doing it without `ToAssociation` isn't that hard either:

```
Dataset[Map[Association, "items" /. json]]
```

Comment: Have you tried more structured hierarchical data?

Comment: @alancalvitti The other part of the OP's question (XML) is answered by WReach (see his comment). I'm taking a stab at HTML [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71914/731), but I don't go as far as putting the data into `Association`.