# Import Stackoverflow data and convert it into dataset

Tags: import, dataset, xml

I have an xml file with the tag data from Stackexchange:
https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackoverflow.com-Tags.7z

After I unzip it I would like to import it to Mathematica to some statistics. I get an XML Object like this:

```
XMLObject[
  "Document"][{XMLObject["Declaration"]["Version" -> "1.0", 
   "Encoding" -> "utf-8"]}, 
 XMLElement[
  "tags", {}, {XMLElement[
    "row", {"Id" -> "1", "TagName" -> ".net", "Count" -> "265332", 
     "ExcerptPostId" -> "3624959", "WikiPostId" -> "3607476"}, {}], 
   XMLElement[
    "row", {"Id" -> "2", "TagName" -> "html", "Count" -> "733157", 
     "ExcerptPostId" -> "3673183", "WikiPostId" -> "3673182"}, {}]
```

How do i convert it to a Mathematica dataset?

I'm aware that a similar question was asked regarding Import itunes xml data. ([Import iTunes xml data and convert it into a dataset or table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58527/import-itunes-xml-data-and-convert-it-into-a-dataset-or-table)) but i could not figure out how to change this code that i can use it for my XML Object.

Some help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: For the snippet you showed ``Dataset@Cases[xml, XMLElement[_, attrs_, _]:>Association[attr], Infinity]`` should work

Comment: @b3m2a1 thank you very much!! It worked perfect.